# VBA Page Break in MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word, page-break

I am trying to combine individual MS Word docs into 1 MS Word doc.  The below code works just fine to do that.  The problem I am having is that I want to insert some code to create a page break after each document so that the next document starts on a new page.  I believe something needs to be added in the Sumit routine.

I have tried every syntax that I can possibly find online.  Nothing is working.

```
'Dim fso As New FileSystemObject

    Dim NoOfFiles As Double

    Dim counter As Integer

    Dim r_counter As Integer

    Dim s As String

    Dim listfiles As Files

    Dim newfile As Worksheet

    Dim mainworkbook As Workbook

    Dim FetchFileClicked

    Dim Folderpath As Variant


Sub Sumit()
    If FetchFileClicked = False Then
        MsgBox "First click the 'Load Control File' button"
        End
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    strRandom = Replace(Replace(Replace(Now, ":", ""), "/", ""), " ", "")
    MergeFileName = "Merger" & strRandom & ".doc"
    MergeFolder = mainworkbook.Sheets("Main").Range("L10").Value

    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

   Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add

   objWord.Visible = True

   Set objSelection = objWord.Selection
   objDoc.SaveAs (MergeFolder & MergeFileName)
    For i = 1 To NoOfFiles
        If Range("B" & i).Value = "Yes" Then
            Set objTempWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
            Set tempDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(Folderpath & "\" & Range("A" & i).Value)
            Set objTempSelection = objTempWord.Selection
            tempDoc.Range.Select
            tempDoc.Range.Copy
            objSelection.TypeParagraph
            objSelection.Paste
            tempDoc.Close
        End If
    Next
    objDoc.Save
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    mainworkbook.Sheets("Main").Activate
    MsgBox "Completed...Merge File is saved at " & MergeFolder & MergeFileName
    FetchFileClicked = False
End Sub



Sub fetchFiles()
    Set mainworkbook = ActiveWorkbook
    Range("A:A").Clear

    Range("B:B").Clear

    Folderpath = mainworkbook.Sheets("Main").Range("L8").Value
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    NoOfFiles = fso.GetFolder(Folderpath).Files.Count
    Set listfiles = fso.GetFolder(Folderpath).Files
    counter = 0
    For Each fls In listfiles
        counter = counter + 1
        Range("A" & counter).Value = fls.Name
        'Range("B" & counter).Value = "Yes"
        Range("A" & counter).Borders.Value = 1
        Range("B" & counter).Borders.Value = 1
        With Range("B" & counter).Validation
             .Delete
            'replace "=A1:A6" with the range the data is in.
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
             Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="Yes,No"
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
        End With
    Next
    Call controlFile
     MsgBox "Control File Loaded"
     FetchFileClicked = True
End Sub


Sub controlFile()

 Worksheets("Main").Range("b1:b6").Formula = "=iferror(VLOOKUP(A1,Table2,MATCH(""load"",Table2[#Headers],0),0),"""")&"""""
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

End Sub
```

I expect each of the individual documents that are added to the newly combined document to be added at the "start of a new page", NOT in the middle of an existing page, like it is today.

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro when typing a page break then putting it in instead of or before `objSelection.TypeParagraph`?

Comment: Cindy thank you so much for your suggestion. It was very helpful to get me to the next step.